# Needing to send emails from Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, automation, outlook, active-directory

bit of a long one...

I have code that splits up an input, searches for a username. If it can find one - it should send an email to the technician (who is in the input as well) saying the username is ready. If it finds multiple, I need it to send a list of all the possible ones to the technician. If it can't find any, I want it to ignore that user completely. I am struggling being able to send an email from Powershell itself. Has anyone got any ideas about the below?

```
$list holds the information
$names = $list | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(",")[0] }; 
$name = $names | ForEach-Object { $_.Split("-")[1]} #Gets the actual names for the users
$emails = $list | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(",")[2]} #Gets the technician email addresses

$count = 0
foreach ($test in $name) {
$indexemails = $emails[$count]
$a,$b,$c = $test | ForEach-Object { $_.Split(" ")}
$displaynamedetails = Get-ADUser -filter {GivenName -eq $b -and Surname -eq $c} | Select-Object samAccountName
if ($displaynamedetails -eq $null) {
$count ++}
else {
$final += $displaynamedetails, $indexemails
$count ++
}}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.2)?

Comment: Yes but the SMTP keeps failing so I can't send from it

Comment: That's not really a PowerShell/coding issue, then.  You need to work out why the server isn't sending the email.  If you think it _is_ an issue with your code, please update your question with the part that is failing.